# How to Activate Debug CallStack via Ctrl + D + C on Resharper Visual Studio Keymap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio C# Default keybinding opens Debug window's Call-stack.

> How do I restore this shortcut, or if Resharper has alternate keys?
>   (Its not visible on their documentation)

Once we have applied `ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_VSscheme`. I lose the ability to open debugger windows quickly.

Unfortuantely resharper doesn't seem to have any shortcut for debugger windows.[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_VSscheme.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReSharper shortcut (`CTRL`+`D`) only works in the text editor or the XAML designer to duplicate a line. The other Visual Studio shortcuts are global and still exist. If they conflict then you could remove or re-map the ReSharper shortcut (under `Tools`->`Options`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`).